# Get child_ids for parent and top pages in Structure

Tags: structure

I need to check the child IDs for a parent or top page in a conditional. However, Structure natively only provides `{structure:child_ids}` and `{structure:child_ids_for:XX}` globals. How can I rig up `{structure:child_ids_for:top}` and/or `{structure:child_ids_for:parent}` functionality?

*(Question first posed this question on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/michaelrog/status/331845261234147329).)*

Answer (score 1):

Combining the native global tags seems to work:

```
{structure:child_ids_for:{structure:top:entry_id}}
{structure:child_ids_for:{structure:parent:entry_id}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really wish I could get this to work inside a conditional... I can get it to render a list of child ids when used on it's own but within a conditional it doesn't work. Ideas?